# How to fix my code and run function when i click on the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> ```
>     
>              
>                       .listItem {
>                        color: rgb(200, 150, 130);
>                     }
>           
>     
>     
>     
>            $(document).ready(function() {
>              $("#list li").addClass("listItem");
>                   });
>               var turn = true;
>     function toggle() {
>     if (turn) {
> ```
>
> ```
> $("#list li").removeClass("listItem");
> $("#list > li").addClass("listItem");
> turn = false;
> } else {
> $("#list li").addClass("listItem");
> turn = true;
> }
> }
> }
> </script>
> </head>
> <body>
> <ul id="list" type="none">
> <li>Item 1</li>
> <ul type="none">
> <li>Item11</li>
> </ul>
> <li>Item 2</li>
> <ul type="none">
> <li>Item21</li>
> </ul>
> <li>Item 3</li>
> <ul type="none">
> <li>Item31</li>
> </ul>
> <li>Item 4</li>
> <ul type="none">
> <li>Item41</li>
> </ul>
> </ul>
> <input type="button" value="Change">
> </body>
> ```

Comment: Add a click handler, call the function? lol

Answer (score 2):

First give your button an Id, let's assume it's '#button' in this case.
Then head over to your jQuery code and add

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps!